# Streaming Binary Over a WCF DataService

Tags: wpf, wcf, .net-4.0, dataservice

The idea is pretty simple, I have a project hosting a WCF DataService, and another WPF Project, I'm referring the service in WPF and It's working great, I want to find out if there's a way to stream binary with the service, and get that binary with the WPF and save it on local disk!

Note: The binaries might be bigger than 200MBs

Answer (score 0):

Everything you send by WCF has to be serializable in some way.  So, yes, it's possible to find a format in which to serialize your binary file.  However, I'm not sure this is the best approach.  If your data service is being served over HTTP, and you're able to use ASP.NET, you may want to consider just using a generic handler (.ashx) to send your binary file provided that you do not just have a static link to the file.

Comment: Do you have any useful links ?